# Converting One-Off Code to Method

Tags: objective-c, methods

I have the following code which takes a touch on one button and draws a border around that button, then makes sure that all the other buttons have no border (8 buttons total).  This is a method in a singleton class called AnswerButtons.  This code works fine.

```
- (IBAction)button1WasTouched:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Hello from button 1");

    // retrieve, modify and update clueAnsState

    NSMutableArray *newCAS = [[GameData gameData].curData objectForKey:@"clueAnsState"];
   [newCAS replaceObjectAtIndex:0
                     withObject:@"2"];
    [[GameData gameData].curData setObject:newCAS
                                    forKey:@"clueAnsState"];

    // Highlight the pressed button & make sure other buttons are not highlighted

    for (NSInteger idx = 0; idx < 8; idx++) {
        NSString *temp = [newCAS objectAtIndex:idx];
        if ([temp isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
            UIButton *b = [[AnswerButtons answerButtons].buttons objectAtIndex:idx];
            [[b layer] setBorderWidth:0.0f];
        }
        if ([temp isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
            UIButton *b = [[AnswerButtons answerButtons].buttons objectAtIndex:idx];
            [[b layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];
        }
    }

}
```

Now, I need to use this code for all 8 buttons, so I should write a method with one argument, the button number to modify (pos).  In the singleton class .m I put which is virtually the same code:

```
    - (void)activateAnswerAtPos:(int)pos {

    // retrieve, modify and update clueAnsState

    NSMutableArray *newCAS = [[GameData gameData].curData objectForKey:@"clueAnsState"];
    [newCAS replaceObjectAtIndex:pos
                      withObject:@"2"];
    [[GameData gameData].curData setObject:newCAS
                                    forKey:@"clueAnsState"];

    NSLog(@"%@", newCAS);

    for (NSInteger idx = 0; idx < 8; idx++) {
        NSString *temp = [newCAS objectAtIndex:idx];
        if ([temp isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
            UIButton *b = [[AnswerButtons answerButtons].buttons objectAtIndex:idx];
            [[b layer] setBorderWidth:0.0f];
       }
       if ([temp isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
            UIButton *b = [[AnswerButtons answerButtons].buttons objectAtIndex:idx];
            [[b layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];
        }
    }
}
```

So I changed the first code chunk to make it a call to the new method:

```
- (IBAction)button1WasTouched:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Hello from button 1");
    [sender activateAnswerAtPos:0];
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm doing something wrong as I get the following exception:

```
2012-03-30 19:41:40.199 P3[6751:f803] Hello from button 1
2012-03-30 19:41:40.201 P3[6751:f803] -[UIRoundedRectButton activateAnswerAtPos:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e709f0
```

I'm not sure what's going on here; several alternatives don't work either and I think my troubleshooting is sending me in the wrong direction.  What's wrong with the way I am calling this method?  Clearly I'm not even getting to run the method.  TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `-activateAnswerAtPos:` on sender, which is the button that was touched. You should instead call it on the instance of the class that defines the `-activateAnswerAtPos:` method. It's not clear from your code what that is, but my guess is self:

```
[self activateAnswerAtPos:0];
```

Comment: Damn!  So simple.  Thanks for that quick answer, I'm back and running again.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to follow what you are trying to do but I would probably send all button actions to one method like this

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)buttonTapped;
{
    NSArray *buttons = [AnswerButtons answerButtons].buttons;

    // some kind of switch statement of logic to perform options depending on which button
    // Can use the following to get the index
    // NSInteger buttonIndex = [buttons indexOfObject:buttonTapped]

    for (UIButton *button in buttons) {
        if (button == buttonTapped) {
            // highlight
        } else {
            // remove highlight
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paul.  My problem was solved about the time you were writing but your code shows me some much leaner ways to do some things than what I've been doing, so it's a bonus.